# Disable softDelete Query filters for navigation properties

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, soft-delete

I use Ef Core 2.1, in which I enabled a soft-delete query filter.

In some cases, I want to retrieve from an entity, a soft-deleted navigation property, but I could not retrieve the data (The navigation property is null because it was soft deleted).

I used this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) (which was written in 2017) as a reference, and it is stated that

> Filters cannot contain references to navigation properties.

I wish to know If there is any way to enable such behaviour.

```
public class Form {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Sprint Sprint {get; set;}
}

public class Sprint: ISoftDeleteable {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name {get; set;}
}

// Indicates that every model that implements this interface should use soft delete.
public interface ISoftDeleteable
{ 

}

 // Both statements have returned null.
 Sprint sprint = applicationDbContext.Forms.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == 1).Sprint;
 Sprint sprint = applicationDbContext.Forms.IgnoreQueryFilters().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == 1).Sprint;
```

As a side note, I wish to state that I use a lazy loading proxy in StartUp.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

Instead of using using 'Include()' and 'ThenInclude()', Because my model, is more complex than the exmplle given here. Using include will make the code more complicated and unmaintainable.

Comment: Did you tried `.IgnoreQueryFilters()`?

Comment: See an edited version of the post. I have tried to use IgnoreQueryFilters, But It does seem to work on nested properties.

Comment: You need to include navigation property. `dbContext.Forms.Include(f => f.Sprint).IgnoreQueryFilters().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == 1).Sprint`

Comment: Is this necessary, If I already use a lazy loading proxy?

Comment: Did you tried to include navigation property? Just curious what is the use case where you need lazy loading?

Comment: Our model is very complex and have more than 20 properties, and each property, has its own nested properties, using 'UseLazyLoadingProxies()' in startup.cs makes the code more maintainable than using 'include()' and 'ThenInclude()'.

Comment: I wouldn't say so, especially for web applications. Very quickly you end up with N+1 queries. As developer I would prefer to explicitly know when I loaded all required data in memory, so I know how to process data.

Answer (score 7):

try this

```cs
var data = DbContext.Set<Table>().IgnoreQueryFilters().ToList();
```

or

```cs
var data = DbContext.TableName.IgnoreQueryFilters().ToList();
```

Comment: See an edited version of my post. I have tried to use IgnoreQueryFilters, But It does seem to work on nested properties.

Comment: you must declare a property for example IsDelete as bool and when a record is soft delete change IsDelete propery to True and set query filter . for example : modelBuilder.Entity<Users>().HasQueryFilter(a => !a.IsDelete);

Comment: I already do that.The problem I face is when I want to retrive the soft-deleted navigation property.

Comment: applicationDbContext.Forms.IgnoreQueryFilters().Include(a=>a.Sprint ).FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == 1).Sprint;

Comment: What you have suggested works. But my model is more complex, than the exmple i have given. So to use 'Include()' and 'ThanInclude()' will be more complicated and unmaintanable. my question is why is this necessary to use 'include()' , If I have already use 'UseLazyLoadingProxies()' in startup.cs

Comment: Are you add services.AddEntityFrameworkProxies() in ConfigureServices method?

Comment: No, I didnt, But i tried to add this in ConfigureServices below the registeration of the applicationDbContext. And it didn't work. ( This time, I have not used Include())