# Entity Framework ByPass QueryFilter / SoftDelete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a user table in which I use a soft delete method to make sure users that want to be deleted are only deleted virtually. This is because the user might still have some costs and we need to send an invoice to them even if they are deleted.

In Entity Framework `OnModelCreating` I use

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserDomain>().Property<bool>("isDeleted");
modelBuilder.Entity<UserDomain>().HasQueryFilter(m => EF.Property<bool>(m, "isDeleted") == false);
```

Now everywhere I get the user, the (soft)deleted users are ignored. Although they still exist in the database.

However, now I want to do a query which includes the deteled users so I can send them an invoice if needed.

I thought I could bypass this by using `context.Users.FromSql([query])`. But that is not true. It still filters out the deleted records.

How can I bypass the `QueryFilter`?

Comment: Use a different DbContext with a different configuration. A DbContext is *not* a model of the database, you don't need to (actually you *shouldn't*) have just one DbContext per app or database. A DbContext is essentially a Unit-of-Work/Bounded Context in DDD terms.

Comment: Moreover, DbContext contains *entities* not tables. Its job is to Map *application* Objects/entities to Relational tables. It's not supposed to be a replica of the database. Nothing prevents you from having Entities with different or fewer properties for different Business contexts that eventually map to the same tables for example. There's no reason to load all of a user's profile to authenticate for example, or load the password hash to display a list of users

Comment: Thnx guys, this is an eye opener for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution would be to just use a different DbContext with a different configuration.

A DbContext is not a model of the database, you don't need to (actually you shouldn't) have just one DbContext per app or database. A DbContext is essentially a Unit-of-Work/Bounded Context in DDD terms.

Moreover, DbContext contains entities not tables. Its job is to Map application Objects/entities to Relational tables. It's not supposed to be a replica of the database.

Nothing prevents you from having Entities with different or fewer properties for different Business contexts that eventually map to the same tables for example.

In a web app, you'd need different data to authenticate a user and different data to display a list of registered users, or display a greeting. There's no reason to load all of a user's attributes to authenticate for example, nor should you have to load the password hash when displaying a list of users.

Comment: Or you could do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56929590/disable-softdelete-query-filters-for-navigation-properties

Answer (score 4):

Use .IgnoreQueryFilters()

```
var list = context.Users.IgnoreQueryFilters();
```